# Updating PostgreSQL JSONB key value by adding 1 to existing key value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Im getting error while updating JSON data

```
CREATE TABLE testTable
AS
  SELECT $${
    "id": 1,
    "value": 100
  }$$::jsonb AS jsondata;
```

and I want to update `value` to 101 by adding 1, after visiting many websites I found this statement

```
UPDATE testTable
SET jsondata = JSONB_SET(jsondata, '{value}', (jsondata->>'value')::int + 1);
```

but above one is giving error "cannot convert jsonb to int"

and my expected output is

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "value": 101
}
```

Comment: please post the table schema for `testTable`

Comment: `testTable` contain only one column `jsondata` type `JSONB`

Comment: postgresql should not be reporting `"cannot convert jsonb to int"` then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the signature of jsonb_set (using `\df jsonb_set`)

```
   Schema   |   Name    | Result data type |                                  Argument data types                                   |  Type  
------------+-----------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------
 pg_catalog | jsonb_set | jsonb            | jsonb_in jsonb, path text[], replacement jsonb, create_if_missing boolean DEFAULT true | normal
```

What you want is this..

```
UPDATE testTable
  SET jsondata = jsonb_set(
    jsondata,
    ARRAY['value'],
    to_jsonb((jsondata->>'value')::int + 1)
  )
;
```